# How to link assets to imported dashboard in Nessus Security Center?

Tags: import, assets, dashboard, network-scan, nessus

I have a configured dashboard in my Nessus Security Center. For each component, I have set an asset, for example the asset of my Linux machines. Now I will create the same dashboard with the asset of my windows machines. 
By exporting into an xml, I have the choice of three methods:

1. Keep references
2. Replace references with placeholder
3. Delete references

If I take the second option, I found no way to replace the placeholders with the reference to my windows asset list.

The only way I found was: going into each cell of each component and set the asset in the "Target Filters" option.

Is there no general setting for the whole dashboard to configure the assets?

P.S: The definition of the components in the export-xml is unusable, if you can't decrypt it.

Answer (score 0):

The first selection should be keep all references.... depending on the version you are running. When you import the new dashboard it should keep everything. If your building out a completely new system and importing things you will have to build new assets or import those also.